Moveable glibc installation, say by setting _rpaths_ when building
Has anyone ever tried to build glibc with rpaths set so that the resulting installation can be moved on the file system, and still work?
This would be helpful for dealing with a sandboxing issue. We want tests/binaries to use our own glibc -- installed in the sandbox -- but we do not a priori know the absolute path of the sandbox directory.


so that the resulting installation can be moved on the file system,

This can not work reliably for reasons explained here.
In addition to the dynamic loader being hard-baked into all executables, GLIBC itself has hard-coded paths that it will use to load components of itself (needed e.g. to handle nsswitch.conf).
While it's possible to redirect both the dynamic loader and GLIBC using "explicit loader invocation": /path/to/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path .... /path/to/a.out, none of that is transparent.

we do not a priori know the absolute path of the sandbox directory.

For this particular use case, you may want to chroot into the sandbox directory -- then you wouldn't care what that directory is -- it will become / for the sandboxee.
